# How to remove the robotic sound from an (almost) isolated vocals

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, vocals, audacity, fl-studio

**THE SITUATION:**

I have look all around for tutorials about isolating the vocals from a song.
There is good material and i have tried several of them.

I obtained the best outcome by combining two tutorials, one mainly based on the Voicetrap plugin for FL Studio, and the other using Audacity.

For reference here are the two tutorials used:

**1. FL STUDIO:**

**2. AUDACITY:**

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Tutorial_-_Vocal_Removal_and_Isolation

(the paragraph is: A technique using Audacity for vocal isolation)

**THE ISSUE:**

I have to say, they did a pretty good job.

The problem is that it remains a nasty robotic sounds in the background that in the end it make it not suitable to use it.

I have tried to make some several test trying to cover that background sounds, but you can hear that is still there and honestly it ruins everything.

**THE QUESTION:**

**How can i remove that robotic background sound that remains after isolating a vocal?** 
There must be a way no? 
At least to clean it a little bit more?

I am using FL Studio 12 and Audacity,  but i am open to trying other software if needed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you include a sample in your question? Otherwise it's difficult to know what you mean by "robotic background". You can use SoundCloud.

Comment: If the sound is noise-like, you can use a denoise process. If it's not, you can remove unwanted sounds harmonic by harmonic using a FFT editor. You can do both in Izotope RX.

Comment: By robotic background i mean what is left after working on the track by isolating the vocals. That youtube video is a perfect example. It does that process two times and both times it remains this robotic background.

Comment: What do you mean by using SoundCloud? What is the best solution for a good denoise process? Audacity, FL Studio or something else?

Comment: You can upload your audio to souncloud.com so you can link it to us so we can hear exactly what's going on. Describing audio with words can be futile. Once we hear it we can help you. The software and technique you'll use depends on that. At the very least give us a time stamp on that 8 minute video, but that won't be as helpful. If you give us audio to download we can work on it and explain you what we did. Otherwise you are betting on someone to find it in that video, download it, edit the relevant part, and only then start working on cleaning the audio. Help us help you.

Comment: Ok, in that youtube video you can hear a very similar thing from 1:12 - 1:42. Sorry for my inexperience. Anyway i didn't want somebody working on it for me. I was asking a general question because it seemed to me a general issue. That by isolating the vocals something of the instrumental is left (that sound robotic to me). In hope somebody know a general way to work around it.

Comment: It's not about working it for you. It's about telling you how we did it. If you upload a sample for us to download (around 1 min) i'll gladly help you.

Comment: Ok. Here there is one minute of the track: https://soundcloud.com/user-769764805/vocal-isolation-attempt-1

Comment: Here i post a second attempt with a little of denoise work made on Adobe Premiere (only because i know that software well and remembered there are some denoise filter): https://soundcloud.com/user-769764805/vocal-isolation-attempt  But probably is better to work on the previous track

Comment: Denoise doesn't work, but you can remove the artifacts through FFT editing (Izotope RX is great for that, I managed to clean a small portion of the audio with it). It'll require *a lot* of work though, probably not worth it, but I can't think of another way.

Comment: Oh.. really no other way? :( With that software i would have to clean second by second each noise right? No other work around? So as a general reply we can say that there is no general way to eliminate the residual of vocal isolation work, except by FFT editing?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Yes, you'd need to clean each little noise individually.